# For the first time form is validating and submitted in ajax but after dynamically content loading ajax form is not submitted in ajax and page reloaded

Tags: ajax, forms, validation

I am validating a form using jquery and then submitting is by submit handler. For the first time its working fine. On success of submit I am refreshing the div content and forms are coming now dynamically but now form validation is not working and ajax submit is not working too.

Comment: **My form validation code looks like**

    $(document).ready(function(){
       $("#organization_info_from").validate({
         rules:{
           company_introduction: {required: true}
         },
         messages:{
           company_introduction: {required: translated_js.company_introduction_required},
         },
         submitHandler: function(form) {
            $.ajax({
             //
            });
            return false;
        }
    });
  });

Comment: **Html form is reloading**
   function refreshTab(tab_id)
   {
     $.ajax({
      url: site_url + "profile",
      headers: {'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name=csrf-token]').attr('content')},
      success: function (response) {
        $(".tab-content").html(response);
      }
    });
  }
  **Now the form validation is not working and also ajax submit is not working**